# Fastest way to determine values matching an interval in an array

Tags: c, arrays, performance

I have a sorted array of `int` going from `x` to `y` (the values of the elements are random but sorted in ascending order using `qsort()`). The program receives various intervals like `<10;50>`, or `<50;100>`. I have the following simple `for` loop to determine if the values in the array are in the set interval, if yes add one to the counter.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arraySize ;i++ )  {        
       if (points[i] >= interval1 && points[i] <= interval2){
            counter++;               
        }
    }
```

I need a faster way than `O(n)` to search through the array, and determine if the value in `points[i]` is in the set interval or not. The values can be in the millions, hence slowing down dramatically.

*The elements in the array can range from 0 to 1000000000 (1e9). The intervals respectively.*

Comment: What about a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)?

Comment: Values are roughly from what to what? x>? y<?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree

Comment: @ringo The elements in the array can range from 0 to 1000000000(1e9). The intervals respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use binary search - for the input interval `[i, j]`, find the index of the smallest integer that is larger than `i`, find the index of the largest integer that is smaller than `j`, and then return the distance between them.

```
ssize_t bin_search_first_larger(int arr[], size_t arr_sz, int val) {
    ssize_t l = -1;
    ssize_t r = arr_sz;
    /* invariant: arr[l] < val && val <= arr[r] */
    while (l+1 != r) {
        ssize_t m = l+(r-l)/2;
        if (arr[m] < val) {
            l = m;
        } else {
            r = m;
        }
    }
    /* l+1 == r && arr[l] < val && val <= arr[r] */
    return r;
}

ssize_t bin_search_last_smaller(int arr[], size_t arr_sz, int val) {
    ssize_t l = -1;
    ssize_t r = arr_sz;
    /* invariant: arr[l] <= val && val < arr[r] */
    while (l+1 != r) {
        ssize_t m = l+(r-l)/2;
        if (arr[m] <= val) {
            l = m;
        } else {
            r = m;
        }
    }
    /* l+1 == r && arr[l] <= val && val < arr[r] */
    return l;
}

ssize_t values_in(int arr[], size_t arr_sz, int x, int y) {
    ssize_t i = bin_search_first_larger(arr, arr_sz, x);
    ssize_t j = bin_search_last_smaller(arr, arr_sz, y);
    return j-i+1;
}
```

The binary search code is adapted from Jon Bentley's *Programming Pearls* (which is well worth a read), where it is shown how binary search can be modified to return either the first occurrence or the last occurrence of a value in a sorted array with duplicates (rather than returning an arbitrary occurrence of a duplicate value). The process is similar for your use case, the difference is subtle.

Note that conceptually, it is assumed that `arr[-1]` is negative infinity, and `arr[N]` is positive infinity (where `N` is the size of the array), but obviously, the code never attempts to access such elements.

Time complexity is `O(log(N))` where `N` is the size of the array, it's hard (impossible?) to get any better than that.

I ran some tests and it appears to work fine for the general case and also for edge cases (no elements in the range, or `y` larger than every element, or `x` smaller than every element, or both `x` smaller than every element and `y` larger than every element), but as you probably know this does not prove the absence of bugs.

Comment: Works like a charm. Except for some mem leaks which i am sorting out at the moment.

Comment: Correction: The mem leaks were on my part, sorry.

Comment: @Supercan Yes, I assumed that when I read your first comment - I thought you were aware of that. This code doesn't perform any memory allocations or any other memory-related operation, so it can't possibly be responsible for leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, trying to take up the challenge to do better than `O(log n)`, here is a `O(1)` (time) solution to get the number of values within a given range `[a,b]`.

Initialization itself, to only do once, is `O(MAXVALUE+NVALUES)`. `MAXVALUE` being the highest value that may appear in the set of data, `NVALUES` is the number of values in the set of data. And according to the question

> - 0 is the lowest value
> - 1,000,000,000 is the highest value
> - set of data is in the millions

`O(1)` requires to allow the program to allocate an array of `MAXVALUE+1 int`. Basically for 1bn values, an array of `1GB x sizeof(int)` (*gcc* on Linux x86_64 that would take typically 4 GB of RAM, or partly swap). Meaning the program has to run on a at least 64 bits machine.

The initial set of data is to be ordered.

**Principle**

- Initialization (once): the `m[0, 1bn]` array at index *i* gets the number of values greater or equal than *i*
- Number of values in the range `[a, b]` is simply `m[a] - m[b+1]`
  (if `b+1` > MAXVALUE, use `0` instead)

Initialization:

```
#define MAXVALUE 1000000000
#define NVALUES     1000000

int *m; // big array

void initialization(int *values)
{
   m = malloc((MAXVALUE+1) * sizeof(*m)); // check if NULL!

   int i,j;

   for(j=0,i=0 ; i<=MAXVALUE ; ) {
      if (j >= NVALUES) m[i++] = 0;
      else if (values[j] >= i) m[i++] = NVALUES-j;
      else j++;
   }
}
```

Get number of values within range `[a, b] a<=b`:

```
int count_in_range(int a, int b) {
   int ma = m[a];
   int mb = b >= MAXVALUE ? 0 : m[b+1];
   return ma-mb;
}
```

`m` has to be freed after all ranges have been counted.

Answer (score 0):

The needed distance is equal to :

```
// position of first element greater than interval2
auto lb = std::upper_bound(array.begin(), array.end(), interval2);
// position of first element greater or equal than interval1
auto ub = std::lower_bound(array.begin(), array.end(), interval1);
// their difference is the number of elements in the needed range
return (ub - lb);
```

The resulting complexity is `O(log N)` since the lower/upper bounds on the sorted array are `O(log N)`.

Edit: sorry, didn't notice the `C` tag. In `C` you need to implement lower/upper bound operations yourself, then. To make your life simplier - you can only impement `lower_bound` and then use `upper_bound` as `lower_bound(interval2 + 1)`.

Comment: The question is tagged C.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have other version of BinSearch, with complexity O(logN) too.

```
    int BinSearch(int *array, int first, int last, int value){

          int m;
          /* Optional Error control */
          if (!array || first<0 || last<first)  return -1;

          while (first <= last){

                  m = (first + last)/2;

                  if(array[m] == value) return m;

                  if(value < array[m]) last = m-1;

                  else
                       first = m+1;
            }
           /* Failure search */
           return -1;
     }
```

The function returns -1 if the value is not in the array or the index where the values is.

You can do a variant that returns 1 if find the value or 0, then you can do

```
      counter += BinSearch_variant(array,first,last,value);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile (`fist < 0` rather than `first`), which shows that you didn't even test the code (or worse yet: you didn't try to compile it). Plus, this is not enough to solve the problem because the interval extremes are not necessarily in the array. The question is not *Give me the code for binary search*, but rather it is about optimizing a specific scenario (binary search definitely plays a role, but this answer is too incomplete to be useful in my opinion).